# using if statement in mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have the following query. I want to show the time if number of Adults is less than 10.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(Adult) AS Number1, Time FROM orders WHERE confirmed = 'Y' and BookDate = '2013-04-01' GROUP BY Time");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($row['Number1'] < '10')
echo '<div class="result">'.$row['Time'].' ('.$row['Number1'].')</div>';

}
```

so it will come out like this...

```
<div class="result">18:00:00 (8)</div>
<div class="result">18:30:00 (5)</div>
<div class="result">19:00:00 (6)</div>
```

However I also want to show that 18:15:00 has 0 Adults.
I have tried adding some if statement like this

```
if (($row['Time'] == '18:15:00') and ($row['Number1'] < '10')) {
echo '<div class="result">'.$row['Time'].' ('.$row['Number1'].')</div>';
}
else {
echo '<div class="result">18:15:00 (0)</div>';
}
```

but it keeps looping. Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the `$row2` ?

Comment: There is no `$row['Adult']`, that should be `$row['Number1']`.

Comment: If you just want to show data for 18:15:00, why don't you put that in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Have edited the code... hopefully explains it better.

Comment: The query will never return any information for times with no rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `break` out of the loop statement, you can use the `break` statement:

```
while(condition){
    if(conditionMet){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this is it:

```
if ($row['Number1'] < '10') {
  echo '<div class="result">'.$row['Time'].' ('.$row['Number1'].')</div>';
} elseif ($row['Time']) == '18:15:00') {
  echo '<div class="result">18:15:00 (0)</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:-

```
if (($row['Time'] == '18:15:00') and ($row['Number1'] < '10')) 
{
echo '<div class="result">'.$row['Time'].' ('.$row['Number1'].')</div>';
}
else 
{
echo '<div class="result">18:15:00 (0)</div>';
}
```

to

```
if ($row['Number1'] < '10') 
{
echo '<div class="result">'.$row['Time'].' ('.$row['Number1'].')</div>';
}
elseif(($row['Time']) == '18:15:00') 
{
echo '<div class="result">18:15:00 (0)</div>';
}
```